# Adding auth token as header to okhttp

Tags: android, http-headers, okhttp

I have the method below for making GET calls. I need to add a header to it, so as to pass the userToken to the server through the header. How do I do that?

```
public static String getJsonStringFromHttpGet(String url) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    try {
        Response responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return responses.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "response exception:");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
...
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .header("Authorization", userToken)
        .build();
...
```

Reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes